# Is there a way to calculate averages using a conditional function similar to (sum ifs, counties, or sum product) in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I have a daily Excel extract from a trouble ticketing system that give ticket ID, Product, Open date and close date (amongst other things). From another spreadsheet I want to be able to subtract, dynamically, the Close dates and Open dates to determine total time open and average the values by product, creating an executive summary.  I could easily add a column to the source spreadsheet to do the individual deltas and then do the averages externally with a combination of SUMIFS, SUMPRODUCT etc. However editing or a full copy of the source data is not a viable option in our case.

Is there a way to do the calculations above outside of the source spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an "array formula" like this

`=AVERAGE(IF(A$2:A$100=E2,C$2:C$100-B$2:B$100))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

where A2:A100 contain products, B2:B100 Open Dates and C2:C100 Close dates and E2 contains a specific product.

That formula will give your the average time open for the product listed in E2

For simplicity I showed the formula as it would appear on the same worksheet - you can easily refer to ranges on another worksheet or even another workbook